# In Aurora Mode, do I have to get my first Grade of Shards from set monsters before I can get the other 8 Grades?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

Because Seamas are literally the first and most numerous enemies of the first area. If I could've gotten Gen from them the first time, I would've?

And then there's Carabosse dropping Rubella after getting Grade 1 from Tamako-Death.

Given how many Carabosse I killed, I bet that *is* how it works.